# javascript class method call from inside another method, results in "moveToCell is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, function, class, runtime-error

I have this class:

```
class AGV {
    constructor(id, x, y, agvcolor, matrixTable) {
        this.id = id;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = agvcolor;
        this.xOffset = 1;
        this.yOffset = 1;
        this.matrix = matrixTable;
    }
    setX(newX) {
        this.x = newX;
    }
    setY(newY) {
        this.y = newY;
    }
    lastCoordinates() {
        return JSON.stringify({
            'x': this.x,
            'y': this.y
        });
    }
    spawn() {
        var xCoord = this.x - this.xOffset;
        var yCoord = this.y - this.yOffset;
        var cell = this.matrix.childNodes[1].children[yCoord].children[xCoord];
        cell.style.background = this.color;
        cell.innerHTML = this.id;
    }
    moveToCell(x, y) {
        console.log("rolling to x: " + x + " y: " + y);
        this.clearPreviousCell(this.x, this.y);
        // offsets are needed to convert array index to actual position
        var xCoord = x - xOffset;
        var yCoord = y - yOffset;
        var cell = this.matrix.childNodes[1].children[yCoord].children[xCoord];
        cell.style.background = this.color;
        cell.innerHTML = this.id;
    }
    clearPreviousCell(x, y) {
        var xCoord = x - xOffset;
        var yCoord = y - yOffset;
        var cell = this.matrix.childNodes[1].children[yCoord].children[xCoord];
        cell.style.background = "#fff";
        cell.innerHTML = "";
    }
    runTask(x, y, z) {
        console.log("Running task. Target: X: " + x + " Y: " + y);
        if (this.x < x) {
            //while (this.x < x) {
            this.x += 1;
            setTimeout(function() {
                moveToCell(this.x, y);
            }, 800);
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

And whenever I call `moveToCell()` function inside function `runTask()`, I get an error stating that the "moveToCell" function is not defined and as so, I cannot update the object's position in the map.

I've also tried `this.moveToCell()` insted, but results in the same problem. I don't understand what is wrong here.

Can anyone please post any thoughts on this? Thanks in advance

Comment: `moveToCell` is a class method, you have to call it as `instance.moveToCell(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the instance to call the method on, which should be `this`.

Also, `this` is not saved in normal closures. Use an arrow function to keep the context.

```
    runTask(x, y, z) {
        console.log("Running task. Target: X: " + x + " Y: " + y);
        if (this.x < x) {
            //while (this.x < x) {
            this.x += 1;
            setTimeout(() => this.moveToCell(this.x, y), 800);
            //}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou, this was exactly it. As you were the first to answer, i've marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: @PedroSousa Thanks for accepting one of the answers. But if you're accepting based on the time rather than content, I answered first and then after couple of mins this answer was posted. Glad we both were able to solve the question for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's inside the class, you need to use the `this` operator. Change it to:

```
this.moveToCell(this.x, y);
```

As you're using it within `setTimeout(function () { ... })`, you need to cache `this`:

```
this.x += 1;
_this = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    _this.moveToCell(this.x, y);
}, 800);
```